# Why does Chrome keep attempting to mount mp4 files when it can't play them?

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome, video

Why does Chrome keep attempting to mount mp4 files when it can't play them?

I am working on a PC Windows 7, IE 10, Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172.

It doesn't matter whether mp4 source line is before or after the object lines, Chrome seems to want to mount the mp4 files even if it can't play them.

I would like to play the mp4 file in IE 10 and the flash equivalent in Chrome, but I can't seem to make any combination of line ordering work.

So far, my only workaround is to use flash in both browsers. But why do I have to? I thought the html5 video tag was supported by both browsers?

Is this the correct way for a flash fallback to be coded, as it doesn't seem to be working.  Is there a way to code this so I don't have to use flash in IE 10, which can play the mp4 files native?

Thanks for whatever assistance you can give me.

Here's a copy of the code generated at http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/

```
<!-- "Video For Everybody" http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
<video controls="controls" poster="Mark.jpg" width="640" height="480">
        <source src="Mark.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"     data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="640" height="360">
              <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
              <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
              <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
              <param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=Mark.jpg&amp;file=Mark.mp4" />
              <img alt="Mark" src="Mark.jpg" width="640" height="480" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
</video>
```

Comment: Chrome (current version 29 by the way) should be able to play an mp4 source - have you checked in Fiddler (or browser network tools) to see if there's a problem serving the file?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal When I make a simple test file on my desktop with this line of code in the body section `<a href="test-video.mp4">play video</a>` my Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m mounts the file but refuses to play it.

Is this a local file issue?

Can you post a url to a simple a href linked mp4 for me to test?

Thanks for replying to my question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VrUHH/ links to just an .mp4 file ... playing fine for me in Chrome on OSX, Windows and iPad

Comment: **Offbeatmammal** Very interesting... I mounted the jsfiddle link in chrome and it played the mp4 video.

Just on a hunch, I mounted the video fo everybody demo [link](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html) in Chrome and nothing played... same behavior as I had with my previous file:/// test, controls show but no video. I went to [link](http://v4e.thewikies.com/) and generated the code for a mp4 only with flash fallback and tried that, nothing played in Chrome, not even the flash fallback.

Comment: I copied the html code from the jsfiddle file you made, pasted it into the body of a html file, and it will not play in Chrome!!!

Why will the jsfiddle mp4 in it's code testing environment play, but when the code is moved to a html doc on my desktop it won't? 

I know I have flash installed, but I didn't even get the flash fallback for the video-for-everybody test. What could be the problem? Why does the jsfiddle mp4 play in the testing environment?

Comment: Can you host what you have somewhere we can see it?

Comment: **Offbeatmammal** There's links in my previous post to the video for everybody demo and also for the code generator. The jsfiddle file supplied the code I pasted into a simple html file I ran off my desktop. Both IE10 and FireFox mounted and played the mp4's, Chrome would not. I also ran the test on another Windows 7 PC running "virgin" Google Chrome, (no addons to Chrome or the computer, auto updated) an got the same results as previously. Google mounts the mp4 but will not play it unless it's in the jsfiddle environment.!.?

Comment: I'd like to see the whole HTML and video in a live environment - I am unable to make Chrome fail the way you are saying so unless I can check the page and the video itself I a at a loss

Comment: **Offbeatmammal**

I just reinstalled Chrome. Same results as I previously hade; mounts mp4 but won't play. I can't provide the "whole HTML and live environment" but you can reproduce it yourself. Have you taken the code out of the jsfiddle environment, pasted it into a file and played it from your desktop? Can you play the link http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html on your computer? Please let me know, as I can't understand why both my "customized" computer and another "virgin" can't play mp4 in Chrome?

Comment: plays, no problem for me on Chrome 30 on OSX (WebM) and in Safari (H.264)